# UITableViewCell get nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell,this is how i create the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SongsCell";
    SongsCell *cell = (SongsCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SongsCell" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        cell = (SongsCell *) vc.view;
    }
```

now i want to get all cells in the table info (parameter from cell) when a button pressed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [songTable numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++)
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [songTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Now i have a problem that this loop give me for `cell` a nil for all the cell that currently not seen in the table.

Comment: I want to loop over all the cells in the table.

Comment: Why do you want to loop through the cells? I think this will not give you the result you expect.

Comment: Thx for the help, i done some other stuff for what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop you are using the method [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW16) of the class `UITableView`. This method return `nil` if the cell is not visible as the documentation says:

> Return Value
>   An object representing a cell of the table or **nil if the cell is not visible** or indexPath is out of range.

The method you thought you were using is the delegate method [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW6) of the protocol `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: can i use the delegate method for this?

Comment: @MTA - See my comment to your question. Please update your question and explain why you want to loop through the cells.